# Cumulative distribution function determines distribution of random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, cumulative-distribution-functions

The distribution of a real random variable is completely determined by its distribution function.
Can someone provide a resource for its proof?
I haven't been able to found anything related to it.

Comment: Since the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ is generated by the sets $\{(-\infty,x] : x\in \mathbb R\}$, the distribution of a random variable is completely determined by the value of $\mathbb P(X\in(-\infty,x])$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cumulative distribution is the integral of the the distribution function. The integral and the function itself always have a 1-1 correspondence, except for constants. However, you know that the total integral must be 1.